# how to parse xml file with xml.dom.minidom which has characters like '%$#*^'?

Tags: python, xml

I've created python script which parse xml (format given below)with xml.dom.minidom. and then send email alerts to email ids defined in xml file along with the other data defined in xml like subject, pages etc. When subject contains characters like '&#@%*' etc. I get an error "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 14, column 36?. Please suggest how to fix this?

```
file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Fax>
<FaxID>1137</FaxID>
<Owner>MUMBAI</Owner>
<IsReceived>True</IsReceived>
<FileName>In201804231733471833E6478.tif</FileName>
<CreateTime>2018-04-23 17:33:54</CreateTime>
<Pages>2</Pages>
<Status>DoneOK</Status>  
<ToFaxNumber></ToFaxNumber>
<ToCompanyName></ToCompanyName>
<ToFaxNumber></ToFaxNumber>
<ToName></ToName>
<FromName>Test Email & Transaction from Test Branch</FromName>
<FromCompanyName></FromCompanyName>
<FromFaxNumber>-6194</FromFaxNumber>  
<SendJobID>0</SendJobID>
<Matter>23-Apr-18 17:33</Matter>
<BillingCode>emailid@example.com</BillingCode>
<CustomCode1>0000482</CustomCode1>
<CustomCode2>Apr 23 2018  5:33PM</CustomCode2>
<Subject></Subject>  
<FromFaxNumber>-6194</FromFaxNumber>
<CallerID>-6194</CallerID>
</Fax>
```

sample script

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import os
import glob


path = r'C:\Users\sachin\Desktop\xmlwatcher'

for xml in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    xmldoc = parse(xml)
    Subject = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('FromName')[0].firstChild.data
    print(Subject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, xml.dom.minidom is right. A correct xml text should not contain a raw `&` character. In xml, `&` is used to introduce entities and should be replaced with `&amp;`.

So any *strict* xml parser should choke on that line because it is illegal.

What can be done?

The best way is to fix the error in the producer and have a correct xml file to process. If it is not possible you can try to fix it by hand and replace all row `&` with `&amp;`.

An simpler and probably more robust way would be to use BeautifulSoup. This one is great at parsing incorrect input and is able to automatically find the best interpretation facing an incorrect input file. Here:

```
t = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Fax>
...
<FromName>Test Email & Transaction from Test Branch</FromName>
...
</Fax>"""

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

fixes the offending `&` and displays:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fax>
 ...
 <fromname>
  Test Email &amp; Transaction from Test Branch
 </fromname>
 ...
</fax>
```

Comment: This looks prominent! Here, you're assigning each xml to variable 't'. my application generates multiple xmls at intervals. will it work with automated procedural code?

Comment: @SachinSalve: this code only tries to explain what the problem is. As I have said, the correct way is to fix the problem *before* processing the files. The 2 other ways are just work arounds and are not detailed.

Comment: bs4 solved the issue. implemented with procedural code too.
thank u @SergeBallesta